# Can I use a gradient in Chart.js without accessing the chart context when the chart is created?

Tags: ember.js, chart.js

In Chart.js, is it possible to create a chart with a gradient as a background color *only* by passing in data or options when creating the chart?

All the tutorials I see involve calling `createLinearGradient` on the chart context when creating the chart, and then passing in the gradient object via the backgroundColor option.

Ideally, I would like to be able to pass data to my chart by doing something like this:

```
datasets: [
  {
    data: myData,
    backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(#FF0000, #00FF00)"
  }
]
```

Or, if it's absolutely impossible to create a gradient without the chart context, then with something like:

```
datasets: [
  {
    data: myData,
    backgroundColor: (ctx) => {
      let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 0);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FF0000');
      gradient.addColorStop(0, '#00FF00');
      return gradient;
    }
  }
]
```

I am unable to touch the chart context (or at least, it would be quite difficult and rather hacky to do so) because I am using [ember-cli-chart](https://github.com/aomran/ember-cli-chart), which as far as I know does not provide a way to access the chart's context.

I'd also be happy just having a clean way to work around this in Ember, if there are suggestions there.

---

*Edit:*

To clarify, I understand that this can be done as [Neophytte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877683/can-i-use-a-gradient-in-chart-js-without-accessing-the-chart-context-when-the-ch/54878185#answer-54878185) suggests below.  The issue is that I cannot access the chart context (`var ctx` in his example) and am looking for a way to create gradients without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn to create ember components yourself, w/o relying on 3rd parties. Otherwise your life as developer always will be full of struggles. It's especially sad in cases like this, when 3rd-party [component](https://github.com/aomran/ember-cli-chart/blob/master/addon/components/ember-chart.js) itself is so simple.

You will need to:

1. Remove `ember-cli-chart` from package.json
2. `npm install chart.js --save-dev`
3. In `ember-cli-build.js` file add `app.import('node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js');` (look into node_modules directory to make sure this is a correct path)
4. Create `ember-chart.js` in `app/components` directory and put component's code there. For code itself, you can copy from [ember-cli-chart](https://github.com/aomran/ember-cli-chart/blob/master/addon/components/ember-chart.js)
5. Now in `didInsertElement` you can do with chart whatever you want

---

People often over-use 3rd-party ember components. Sometimes using 3rd-party component makes sense: when it is complex and provide enough flexibility and value. But often using 3rd-party components just limits you.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid this, but I think you're right. Got it working, mostly, at least, now I'm just futzing with Chart.js stuff... Will keep that in mind about overusing 3rd party tools for little things like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this was add multiple stops:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 1200, 0, 0);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#80b6f4");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.2, "#94d973");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, "#80b6f4");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "#94d973");
```

Hope that helps you get started

Example: http://neophytte.mine.nu/portfolio/skills2.html

Comment: The issue is that I don't have access to ctx. My constraint is essentially that the only things I have access to are the data and options parameters being passed to the new Chart.